# Why does my :active selector lose its click event state on scale tranformation?

Tags: html, css

I designed a button for a website and tried to add `transform: scale(0.95);` on a click event (using the `:activate` CSS selector).

```css
a.btn, input[type="submit"].btn, label.btn, button.btn {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: solid 1px #282828;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 17px;
}
a.btn:active, input[type="submit"].btn:active, label.btn:active, button.btn:active {
  transform: scale(0.95);
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Show more recipes" class="btn"/>
```

If the user clicks on the border of the button, the `:active` state reduces the icon and the cursor no longer covers the button, and probably no longer triggers the click event. If the user clicks inside the `scale(0.95)` area, the click event is triggered as normal.

[image: Scale lost click example]

I am trying to keep the click event; I tried to apply an invisible `:before` panel with no success, since `input[type='submit']` does not support it, and was hoping someone solved this issue already.

*Edit Jan 14th: Issue has been rewritten now using `input[type='submit']` which cannot contain elements.*

Comment: Make the content(button look) with another element in the button or anchor, and put the transform on the new element inside of the button. This way when you click the button, you get the transform and the js triggering since the actual button isn't shrinking

Comment: @sebastienbarbier can you make a jsfiddle. I can't see any problem on button click here is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e14drmp8/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily work around this

Make the content(button look) with another element in the button or anchor, and put the transform on the new element inside of the button. This way when you click the button, you get the transform and the js triggering since the actual button isn't shrinking

here is a simple example

```js
document.getElementById('moreRecipes').addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

```css
button.btn span {

    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: solid 1px #282828;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 17px;
    display: block;
}
button.btn:active span {
    transform: scale(.95);
}
```

```html
<button id="moreRecipes" class="btn">
  <span>Show more recipes</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Great suggestion, would definitely work and solve my case, thanks a lot. Will try to find a way without editing HTML using `:after` and `:before` may be ... since this button is already used EVERYWHERE this would be easier , but should be fine. Thanks .

Comment: Sorry but will have to reopen this question, your solution does not work with `input[type='submit']` elements .

Comment: this is now a completely different question, I suggest you ask it as a new post. Also, `input` submit buttons are not that straight forward to work with. You could use the solution for your button and easily submit the form via js

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `click` event you actually waiting for the both: `mousedown` and `mouseup` events and you just lose it on the `mouseup` part.

use the `moousedown` event and it will work for you.

Change your line to:

```
document.getElementById('moreRecipes').addEventListener('mousedown', showMore);
```

Comment: Oh yes, true! I didn't think about it like this but worry if the user want to drag it or click and wait it will act not as expected ... will probably try a different hack but thanks for your answer 

Comment: Then you can place your button in a `div` and to wait for `mouseup` event on the `div`, it will work because you change only the size of the button, and the size of the div stays permanent.

Comment: Some element will not be javascript driven, like links or `input['submit']` elements, could be nice to rewrite the question I guess 

Answer (score 1):

## `:active` Indefinitely

There's a way to have `:active` go on indefinitely or until the user clicks something else that becomes `:active`.

1. Set a `transition: 0.5s` on the `input:active`
2. Set `input` transition: 99999s`

The input transition to `transform:scale(0.95)` takes `0.5s` ***but*** the transition back to normal will take about 28 hours or until the user clicks something that becomes `:active`.

BTW if you want a submit button that can hold content then:

```
<button type='submit'>Show more recipe</button>
```

A submit button usually is used to send a form which means that the whole page reloads. I'm assuming that you are not using a form. If so, then using a submit button has as much use as a normal button.

### Demo

```css
.btn {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: solid 1px #282828;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 17px;
  transition: 99s;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.btn:active {
  transform: scale(.95);
  transition: 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn">Show more recipes</button>
<input type='submit' class='btn' value='Show more recipes'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the very best solution, but the only thing that I can think of that doesn't mean rewriting all your html.

Use a box shadow to simulate a border. Now, increase the real border, set to transparent, to get click events.

In the snippet, i Have changed the border color (well, the inset shadow) to red, and set a partial transparent blue color to the border, to make the way it's working clearer.

As a side note, you don't need to perfectly match the final dimension, even if it is a little greater than necesary will not be noticeable.

```css
a.btn, input[type="submit"].btn, label.btn, button.btn {

    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: solid 0px rgba(0,0,255,0.1);   /* should be transparent */
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px red;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

input[type="submit"].btn:active {
    transform: scale(.95);
    border-top-width: 5px;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    border-right-width: 14px;
    border-left-width: 14px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-left: -14px;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Show more recipes" class="btn"/>
```

Comment: Same idea :) I'd use `rgba(0,0,0,0.01)` instead of transparent just in case IE11 would ignore things that are perfectly transparent (had a bad experience with click on an _initially_ transparent background that'd get ignored as if there was `pointer-events: none` on it >.<)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are kidding that this button is already used EVERYWHERE. :)

Let's assume we have a technical challenge and our goal is to apply the `transform: scale(0.95);` rule to the button on click.
We cannot change the button by itself because of some "unknown" reasons.

The only pseudo-class that can help us is `:active`. It works on anchor and button elements when they are activated.

The solution would be to wrap the button into an anchor element and write a selector.

`a:active input['submit'] {...}`

I've updated the snippet. The gray area shows where a user can click to apply the pseudo-class. You can adjust the size of this area and remove the gray background.

```css
a.btn, input[type="submit"].btn, label.btn, button.btn {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: solid 1px #282828;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 17px;
}
.wrapper:active input[type="submit"],
a.btn:active, input[type="submit"].btn:active, label.btn:active, button.btn:active {
  transform: scale(0.95);
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<a class="wrapper">
  <input type="submit" value="Show more recipes" class="btn"/>
</a>
```

BTW, I have a course about [CSS Selectors](https://www.udemy.com/css3-selectors-h/?couponCode=SOVERFLOW2019) if you would like to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add an unnoticed amount of `transition-duration` and `transition-delay` to the transformed element.

```
a.btn, input[type="submit"].btn, label.btn, button.btn {
    // ...
    transition-duration: .01s;
    transition-delay: 0.05s;
}
```

That amount of delay is enough for JS to fire the event on the correct element. Thus, the event will fire during the delay time and it will never go unnoticed as it's low.